# meaning of segment outgoing in expedia air api result

Tags: php

I am implementing expedia Air API in my php web site. I have sent air availability result and I got the result (in xml format). In the result there is a term segment

`outgoing="true" and segment outgoing="false"`

what is it mean? I read the API doc several times. But I couldn't solve my problem. I think segment `outgoing="true"` means it's the flight from my departure place (i.e. towards the destination) and segment outgoing false means flight starts from my arrival place. I will explain what I mean

If I want to send a round trip request (Cochin to Delhi). From this example

```
Segment outgoing true means -> flight from Cochin to Delhi
Segment outgoing false means -> flight from Delhi (return flight)
```

Is my concept is correct? If not please give me a reply
Also how I will find out the price from the xml result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sure, i know how every one of the millions of apis work.

Comment: then please tell me what is segment outgoing and how i will find out the price of each flight from my xml result

Comment: could you please add the documentation link; maybe if we read it we might figure it out